# spinner crashing using onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

Good day
I have a customized spinner and it shows the string array without any issue. But when I add the onItemSelectedListener my application will crash when loading the fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
  auth = Firebase.auth
  // show back button
  val activity = activity as? MainActivity
  activity?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

  val result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_key, container, false)

  val spinner: Spinner = result.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Category)
  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
     requireContext(), R.array.keyCategory, R.layout.spinner_item
                                 ).also { adapter ->
     spinner.adapter = adapter
  }
  // without adding the below, the application will work smoothly
  spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
     override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
     }

     override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
     }

  }
  return result
```

}

Could you please help, is there something conflicting with the spinner that pushed the application to crash?

Thank you.

Comment: What crash message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines

```
TODO("Not yet implemented")
```

`TODO` throws  `NotImplementedError`

Comment: Good catch, for some reason, I through it is commented :P

Comment: Haha, gets us all, happy coding